# Получение кода программы с сервера

Tags: c#

Возник вопрос, можно ли реализовать получение кода программы с сервера и последующий его запуск? Если, да, то подкиньте статей, пожалуйста.

Comment: >получение функций программы с сервера

эммм...что?

Comment: @DreamChild Кода программы*

Comment: кода на каком языке?

Comment: @nullptr C#

Comment: можно на лету исполнять js, php, а насчет с# я не уверен, поскольку он должен компилироваться в байт-код сначала, а только потом исполнятся

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function

Comment: Вы код полученный выполнять хотите или вам нужно получить команду и отплясывая от нее что-то выполнить?

Comment: Для того, чтобы запустить код на клиенте, у вас должны быть серьёзные права. Если на машине клиента стоит ваш софт, разговаривающий с сервером, проблем нет. Если клиентская часть бежит в браузере, никто вам не даст откомпилировать и запустить код, разве что вы убедите юзера установить плагин.

В общем, расскажите подробнее о вашей проблеме.

Comment: @VladD Ну, к примеру, на сервере лежит `MessageBox.Show("!!!!");`. Я получаю этот текст с сервера, и мне нужно его выполнить, как код.

Comment: А, у вас на сервере _исходник_! Тогда смотрите на принятый ответ.

Comment: Существует прекрасный пример динамической компиляции от VladD: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/263955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Для этого нужно использовать встроенный в .NET Framework [компилятор](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) C#.