# Выполнение кода из textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите реализовать такую идею:
Ввожу в textbox1 определенный код и при нажатии на кнопку он выполняется.
Идеи с if(...) не подойдут

Например:
Ввожу в textbox: MessageBox.Show("Сообщение");
Нажимаю на кнопку
И выполняется этот код

Comment: Код на C# или на придуманном вами языке? В каком _контексте_ он выполняется — доступны ли классы текущей программы и её переменные? Судя по всему, вам сюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom

Comment: Код конечно же C#

Answer (score 29, accepted):

А давайте воспользуемся новомодным Roslyn API.

Для начала, нам понадобится nuget-пакет `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`, добавьте его через `References` → правая кнопка мыши → `Manage NuGet Packages...`.

Теперь, сам скрипт. Модельный класс будет очень простым, т. к. всё уже написано за нас:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
```

```
class Script
{
    ScriptState state;

    public static async Task<Script> Create(
        IEnumerable<Assembly> references, IEnumerable<string> usings)
    {
        var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(references).WithImports(usings);
        var state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync("", options);
        return new Script() { state = state };
    }

    public async Task<object> ExecuteNext(string code)
    {
        state = await state.ContinueWithAsync(code);
        return state.ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Вот собственно и вся сложность.

Пользоваться так:

```
// какие DLL должны быть доступны?
static Assembly[] references = new[]
    {
        typeof(object).Assembly,
        typeof(Uri).Assembly,
        typeof(Enumerable).Assembly,
        typeof(MessageBox).Assembly
    };

// какие юзинги должны быть доступны?
static string[] usings = new[]
    {
        "System",
        "System.IO",
        "System.Text",
        "System.Windows"
    };
```

```
// инициализация
Script script = await Script.Create(references, usings);
```

```
// выполнение одной команды:
try
{
    var result = await script.ExecuteNext(cmd);
    LastResult = result?.ToString() ?? "<no output>";
    IsLastGood = true;
}
catch (CompilationErrorException ex)
{
    LastResult = string.Join(" // ", ex.Diagnostics);
    IsLastGood = false;
}
```

---

Я прикрутил простейший интерфейс, выглядит так:

[image: ура! склад!]

Проект лежит здесь: https://github.com/vladd/EvalUITest

---

Различная полезная литература:

- [Scripting API Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples)
- [In-memory C# compilation (and .dll generation) using Roslyn](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/12/in-memory-c-sharp-compilation-using-roslyn)
- [Getting Started C# Syntax Analysis](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Analysis)
- [Compiling C# Code Into Memory and Executing It with Roslyn](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn)

Comment: Отличный пример! :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper: У меня всё никак не было повода попробовать новый Roslyn API :)

Comment: Молодцы, креативно! Очень часто задумывался над тем как пишут компиляторы :D Даже фантазировал над созданием своего компилятора, интересно, а если этот код в линуксе скомпилировать он будет работать?)

Comment: @pavel1787mego: С последним Mono? Должен по идее. Всё должно работать, кроме сборки `System.Windows`

Comment: Можно получить исходник с простым интерфейсом в ознакомительных целях?

Comment: @Varagian: Да, выложил на гитхаб: https://github.com/vladd/EvalUITest

Comment: @VladD у меня стоит VS 2013 года, и я не могу установить nuget-пакет, из-за того, что версия nuget устарела. Я посмотрел на сайте nuget, новых версий на VS13 нет, для работоспособности данного проекта мне придется обновиться до VS 2015?

Comment: @Varagian: По идее, можно просто скачать новый nuget.exe.

Comment: @Varagian: https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Answer (score 6):

```
private void btnCompile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Здесь код из твоего TextBox'а
    string code =
        @"class EntityCollection : System.Collections.Generic.List<Entity> {}

        class Entity
        {
        public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Age { get; set; }
        }";

    // Получаем интерфейс компилятора
    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

    // Задаём параметры компиляции
    CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
    compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    compilerParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
    compilerParameters.WarningLevel = 4;

    // Цепляем референсные сборки
    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

    // Компилируем код
    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, code);

    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sbExceptions = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
        {
            sbExceptions.AppendLine(
                "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                ", ‘" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        throw new Exception("Exception raised while compiling your code: nn" + sbExceptions);
    }

    // Получаем скопилированную сборку
    Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;

    // Ищем наш тип "EntityCollection"
    Type type = assembly.GetType("EntityCollection");

    // Создаём экземпляр этого класса
    IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Ищем наш второй тип и порождаем его экземпляр
    Type eType = assembly.GetType("Entity");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(eType);

    // Задаём его свойства
    eType.GetProperty("Name").SetValue(obj, "Sanjay", null);
    eType.GetProperty("Age").SetValue(obj, 30, null);

    // Добавляем в нашу же коллецию
    list.Add(obj);

    // Делаем с ней что-нибудь
    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}
```

Исходная статья [здесь](http://paxcel.net/blog/how-to-programmatically-compile-and-use-code-using-c-compiler/).