# Как реализовать строчную отладку кода в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, отладка, компиляция

Добрый день!

У меня имеется код (c#), который я формирую динамически. К примеру, сформировался код следующего вида:

```
NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application excel = new NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\mail.xml");
while (true)
{
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
     break;
}
```

Я запускаю этот код при помощи Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting, в отдельном делегате и всё ОК.
Но теперь мне необходимо по-шагово отладить данный код. Т.е. фактически, я хочу остановиться в том месте, где мне необходимо и получить все значения локальных/глобальных переменных (классический debug).

Каким образом я могу реализовать такую логику?

UPDATE:

В итоге сделал способом, который обсуждался ниже, через Scripting API. Чтобы отслеживать текущий блок(этап) кода, перед каждым шагом я вставляю ко, который меняет специальный параметр текущего домена (в него передается UID шага). Этот параметр считывается из главного домена (из которого запускается выполнение кода).

Comment: Хм... А что если в код добавить System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() ?

Comment: А вы уверены, что пошли правильным путём? Какую _реальную_ задачу вы решаете? Почему бы просто не параметризировать ваш код, а не пытаться принести в него `eval`?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @VladD Задача следующая: хочу сделать что-то, вроде визуального редактора кода. Есть блоки, которые агрегируют несколько строк кода. Например, первые две строки из примера выше - это один блок "Инициализировать Excel". Для этого дела хочу сделать отладчик (по блокам кода).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Огоооо, ну вы и задачу себе поставили. Писать полноценный отладчик — сложно. Посмотрите сюда на [список всех отладочных интерфейсов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/debugging-interfaces)!

Но для простых случаев — выполнение куска кода и проверка переменных — можно выехать на scripting API. Вот пример (основанный на [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/10105)):

```
var cmd = "int x = 10; int y = 20; string z = (x + y).ToString();";
ScriptState state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync(cmd);
foreach (var v in state.Variables)
    Console.WriteLine($"var {v.Name}, type = {v.Type.Name}, value = {v.Value}");
```

Он выдаёт:

```
var x, type = Int32, value = 10
var y, type = Int32, value = 20
var z, type = String, value = 30
```

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал данный вариант и он отлично подходит, если бы не стоял вопрос с вложенными действиями. К примеру, у меня есть If или, как в примере из вопроса "while". Получается я не смогу пройти внутри while по строкам, а только весь while целиком...

Comment: Хмм, возможно в исполняемый код можно добавлять метки, которые будут останавливать поток и ожидать ввода из управляющего потока. Какие варианты есть? Что-то вроде Console.ReadLine()?

Comment: @Serovkir: Я не видел у scripting API возможности выполнять действия «по кусочкам». В принципе, в скрипте можно вызывать внешние callback'и. Но я не знаю, как получить состояние скрипта в момент, когда он ещё не закончил пробег. Боюсь, для этого вам нужно пользоваться «взрослыми» отладочными интерфейсами.