# Подключение сторонних библиотек при динамической компиляции

Tags: c#, компиляция

Как при динамической компиляции файла в C# добавить в него ссылку на стороннюю библиотеку (например SQLite)? В обычном проекте я просто установлю все через Nuget но как быть с файлом который компилируется динамичекси ? Вот пример без сторонних библиотек :

```
Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> 
                { 
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"} 
                };
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters 
{
OutputAssembly = directoryName,
GenerateExecutable = true
};
//добавляем стандартную бибиотеку
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll"); 
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
```

Здесь `source` это массив строк с кодом:

```
string source = 
        @" namespace Foo 
{ 
public class Bar 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Bar.SayHello(); 
    } 

    public static void SayHello() 
    { 
        System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World""); 
    } 
} 
}"
```

Пока все просто, но что если нужно добавить пользовательскую или иную библиотеку которая не входит в стандартные библиотеки и через `ReferencedAssemblies.Add(...)` dll не добавить? После того как файл будет динамически скомпилирован требуемая `Dll` будет находится в той же папке что и исполняемый файл - стоит ли указывать путь ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/218063

Answer (score 0):

```
string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string[] dlls = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll");
foreach(string dll in dlls) compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(dll);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]