# Компилятор ругается на чтение знаков в стабе

Tags: c#

Есть исходный код в ресурсах ( stub.txt )

В Стабе есть такой код:

```
public static bool IsInternetAvailable
{
   get
   {
     if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
     {
       return InternetGetConnectedState(out int description, 0);
     }
      return false;
    } 
}

try
{
   ....
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    File.AppendAllText("Error.txt", $"Вид ошибки: {ex.Message}");
}
```

В билдере компилирую код из ресурсов

```
private void CreateBuild(string ConsoleTitleView)
{
    var Result = Properties.Resources.Stub;
    Result = Result.Replace("[Title]", "Test");
    Result = Result.Replace("[Description]", "Test");
    Result = Result.Replace("[Company]", "Test");
    Result = Result.Replace("[Product]", "Test");
    Result = Result.Replace("[Copyright]", "Test");
    Result = Result.Replace("[TITLE_CONSOLE]", ConsoleTitleView);

    var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } };

 CompilerResults results;
 using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions))
 {
     var Params = new CompilerParameters { OutputAssembly = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/build.exe", GenerateExecutable = true, CompilerOptions = "/t:winexe" };

     Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
     results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, Result);
 }
     if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Good");
     }
     foreach (CompilerError compilerError in results.Errors)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(compilerError.ErrorText);
     }
}
```

На выходе получаю ошибки:

return InternetGetConnectedState(out int description, 0 **)**; в этой строке получаю ошибку:

> error CS1525: Недопустимый терм ")" в выражении
>
> error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

Меня кидает на ошибку в стабе.
Почему компилятор так реагирует на эти символы?

Comment: Что такое «билдер»?

Comment: `"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"` - а эта версия разве поддерживает $?

Comment: @tym32167, Вы правы, хорошое замечание, забыл что на нижних версия не поддерживается этот знак `$`

Comment: @VladD, Динамическая компиляция исходного файла. =) Вы же знаете.

Comment: @Дмитрий, ну да, нужен компилятор, поддерживающий C# 6.0

Comment: @АндрейNOP, А такой есть? С другими компиляторами не работал.

Comment: Ну конечно есть, как-то же мы код компилируем

Comment: Вот сюда загляните: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Сложно с Roslyn ( нужно понять его ). А можете небольшой пример привести с моим примером? Я конечно же почитаю внимательно что там пишут как им пользоваться.

Comment: Нашёл что-то вроде: `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider()` говорят что с помощью него можно нормально компилировать, что вы скажите(народ) ?