# Как сравнивать уравнение по заданной формуле и получать от туда нужные переменные?(TextBox) C#

Tags: c#

Как сравнивать уравнение по заданной формуле в TextBox? 
Например квадратное уравнение ax^2+bx+c=0. И как потом из заданного уравнения например(4x^2 + 5x + 12 = 0), как отсюда получить значения a, b, c.

Comment: 1. Регулярки. 2. Написать парсер

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705895/10105