# (C#) Можно ли использовать лямбда-выражение, хранимое в переменной типа string, и как это сделать?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Допустим, мы имеем класс "А", и массив, заполненный объектами этого класса:

```
    public class A
    {
        public int power;
        public int temp;
    }

    public A[] ArrayOfA = new A[99]; //Допустим, этот массив полон данных.
```

Теперь используя LINQ нам нужно отсортировать этот массив используя лямбда-выражение, вроде такого:

```
        public void Sort()
        {
            ArrayOfA = ArrayOfA.Where(x => x.power > 220 && x.temp < 100).ToArray();
        }
```

**Вопрос заключается в следующем:** Есть ли способ применять подобные лямбда-выражения, если они записаны в переменную-строку? *(как указано ниже, например)*

```
        string lambdaInString = "x => x.power > 220 && x.temp < 100";

        public void Sort()
        {
            ArrayOfA = ArrayOfA.Where(lambdaInString.ToLambda()).ToArray();
            //Очевидно, ToLambda() не существует изначально, это пример.
        }
```

Иначе говоря, как можно реализовать расширение "ToLambda()", которое будет преобразовывать строку в съедобное для C# лямбда-выражение?

*Было задано много вопросов о том, где мне нужно применять подобную задачу, поэтому поясню:*

В двух словах: мне нужно реализовать паттерн, в котором объект заранее определённого класса (В примере - класс "А") должен подходить под условия, которые записаны из вне (условно их записывает пользователь, не имеющий доступа к самому коду и я могу получить их в виде переменных типа string), а если объект класса попадает под это условие, то с ним проводится определённое действие (сортировка, как в примере, или что-то схожее). Для подобного рода условий мне отлично подходят лямбда-выражения, однако тот факт что они не пишутся в коде изначально и создало эту проблему.

Comment: А какую задачу вы хотите решить данным инструментом? Есть подозрение, что её решить гораздо проще, чем при помощи парсинга строки в лямбду.

Comment: Вы скорее всего решаете какую-то более общую задачу неправильным путём. Расскажите, какая ваша _настоящая_ проблема.

Comment: Есть Dynamic LINQ. Но сперва скажите, откуда берутся выражения в строках? Наверняка вместо составления строк можно сразу составлять выражения.

Comment: По вашим просьбам обновил вопрос, добавив контекста к своей задаче.

Comment: Опять не то. Как именно пользователь будет вводить условия? Скорее всего, в GUI будет жать кнопки, чекбоксы и т. п.?

Comment: Нет, речь идёт о строке. Пользователь вводит строку, а программа использует эту строку в качестве условия для взаимодействия с массивом объектов класса, к которому данное условие применимо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/373567, можно попробовать распарсить как `Expression` средствами Roslyn. Но для конкретной задачи я бы написал свой парсер по типу `power > 220 and temp < 100`, можно предварительно что-то подобное на гитхабе поискать. Это как минимум безопаснее, чем давать пользователю писать C# код. А можно просто собрать билдер такого запроса прямо в интерфейсе. Задача при любом раскладе не тривиальная, но и не космически сложная.

Comment: Принято: пользователь вводит строку. Значит, используйте библиотеку Dynamic LINQ.