# В C# После компиляции с помощью Roslyn, создается exe, но не запускается корректно

Tags: c#, компиляция, roslyn

Вот код для компиляции

```
public void CreateTest(string filePath, int a, int b)
        {

            var pc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Verb = "runas",
                    Arguments = $@"""C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Console.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Runtime.dll"" -r:""C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll"" ""{filePath}.cs"" -out:""{filePath}.exe""",
                    FileName = "dotnet",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                }
            };

            pc.Start();
            string stdoutx = pc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string stderrx = pc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            pc.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine("Exit code : {0}", pc.ExitCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Stdout : {0}", stdoutx);
            Console.WriteLine("Stderr : {0}", stderrx);
```

Вот сама ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так все перечисленные при сборке референсы надо видимо в каталог с исполняемым файлом поместить?

Comment: @aepot давай я объясню что хочу сделать.  Я от пользователя получаю файл с исходным кодом, входные параметры и эталонные параметры. Компилирию, запускаю exe, а потом сравниваю получившийся значения с эталонными.  Я думаю, будет не очень с файлом хранить все референсы.

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/373567), другими словами, собирать экзешник совсем не нужно для этого.  Возможно не совсем скриптование надо, но собрать cs файл и выполнить в нем какой-то метод тоже возможно.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое