# Прочтение URL и выполнение кода по URL

Tags: c#

Как можно сделать так что-бы при нажатии на кнопку брался код с сайта "https://raw.github.com/..." и выполнялся при нажатии на кнопку (ReadUrl)

Пожалуйста помогите мне

(Кто не понял я хочу сделать примерно так)

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            text = ReadURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...");
            string button3 = text
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/220553