# Как сделать скомплированную C# программу self-contained?

Tags: c#, .net, компиляция

Напсал C# программу которая компилирует другую C# программу:

```
string src = @"
    using System;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello world"");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
";
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "client.exe", false);
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, src);
```

проблема в том что когда программа компилирует client.exe, этот файл не self-contained и для своего запуска требует установленного .NET Framework, и я не знаю как через код сделать файл self-contained

Comment: `CSharpCodeProvider` создаёт код для .NET Framework. Между тем, self-contained - это понятие из .NET Core. Для создания такой сборки нужно использовать компилятор Roslyn. См. [CSharpCompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpcompilation?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) и т. п.

Comment: Начните с версии дотнета, которую используете. Если это .NET Framework приложение, то никак. Если это .NET Core приложение, то используйте Roslyn для работы с кодом. Чтобы собрать приложение, потребуется создание проекта, далее с помощью команды dotnet его можно собрать как Self-Contained. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: @aepot вы наверное меня не поняли, данный код что я предоставил выше компилирует другую .exe программу, компиляция с помощью команды дот нет тут попросту невозможна

Comment: Я поискал пару минут, как такое сделать. Как-то тухло... Похоже, вам предстоит быть первопроходцем.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а есть какие то языки программирования на которых данную задачу можно было бы решить проще? я вот думаю, может стоит написать билдер программы на другом языке и запихнуть в .dll, и вызывать из под основной программы?

Comment: **Какую** задачу? Уточните.

Comment: Мне надо чтоб программа A компилировалла из сурс кода программу Б, на C# у меня это не вышло и  я сейчас думаю над тем чтоб переписать все на другой яп и даже не знаю что можно выбрать

Comment: @Sheud все я правильно понял. Вам нужна сборка в виде одного файла на диске. Создаете проект из своего кода через dotnet new console, копируете туда свой код для сборки в Program.cs, и публикуете через dotnet publish как я вам показал ссылкой выше. Если исходные файлы после этого не нужны, удаляете. Зачем вам здесь компиляция прямо в коде - я без понятия, вы не сообщили. Нужен экзешник - вперёд, документация есть.

Comment: Смотрите, мне нужна .exe программа которая будет компилировать другую .exe программу даже при условии что на компьютере не установлен .NET, проблема в том что .exe программа которую я компилирую с помощью своей программы требует установленный .NET Framework, а на .NET Core данный код не работает

Comment: Вам выше вроде все ясно сказали, интересно, что не понятно? Попробую объяснить более доходчиво: Вы используете `CSharpCodeProvider`, который доступен **только** в .NET Framework, через него можно собрать только его. Но вы просите `self` сборку, которая появилась **только** в .NET. Также вы пытаетесь отказаться от фреймворка, когда как .NET Framework это не может, он **обязан** иметь установленный у клиента фреймворк (который кстати из коробки есть на любой Windows), .NET позволяет это, да, но для этого вам нужен Roslyn (не факт, что он это может), либо как сказали выше, собирать через консоль.

Comment: Так бы сразу. Вы не сможете ничего толкового собрать, если .NET SDK не установлен. Для self-contained сборки требуется SDK. И завязывайте использовать устаревший Framework, для него 100% решения нет. Для нового .NET можно попробовать собрать, но это будет не просто, библиотеки придётся ручками (кодом) подкладывать и сборщик с собой таскать. В целом на новом .NET возможно, но не просто. А так, исходная задача, зачем это всё, не ясна.

Comment: _"на .NET Core данный код не работает"_ - там по-другому компилируется, через Roslyn, который кстати может намного больше всяких штук, чем CSharpCodeProvider. Вам выше писали, а вы как-будто не обращаете внимания на то что пишут. Вот ссылочка для знакомства https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705977/373567